# Launch different unity3d projects in a android app

Tags: android, android-activity, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to create a simple android App that lets me launch several AR demos created in Unity3D.

I've exported one unity3d project to a "google android project" and then copied the contents of that project to my app project (android Studio). That way I manged to launch the unity project in a new activity, when clicking a button.

However, I can't copy the files from the 2nd unity project as they would overwrite the ones from the 1st project.

Is there another way to launch unity projects exported to android, in different activities?

**EDIT**:
I changed my approach from copy pasting android unity export files, to importing the android unity project as a module and again, it works for one demo, but when importing another project I get this error:

```
E:\Projects\MultiProjectTest\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\app_banner.png: error: Duplicate file.
E:\Projects\MultiProjectTest\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
```

Comment: I have not tried to do this myself, but if you got that to work...Can you not place the project files each in their own associated file and have your app on click enter the specific file and use its associated project files?

Comment: How would I do that?